# How to login with “UserName” instead of “Email” in DotNetCore

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I am using .net-core version 3.0.  I am attempting to switch the built-in identity scaffolding to username login instead of email. However, the Controller, Models, and Views for the login/register pages are abstracted...   How can I accomplish what I am attempting to do?

Comment: Look into Identity in asp.net, there is good documentation. Start by creating a model and referencing `IdentityUser`, something like `public class User : IdentityUser` In `Startup.cs` you will have to specify `services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>()` etc

Comment: Here is a link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio
I would suggest start by creating the models including the user model, then on first `add-migration` look at what is migrating on the `AspNetUsers` table, adjust from there, then add  `AddIdentity` to the `Startup.cs` class, and finally figure out the controllers for actually creating users